WebSocket Disconnects After 60-70 Seconds in FastAPI (Uvicorn) – Works in Postman, Fails in Browser and Mobile Clients
I’m implementing a WebSocket connection using FastAPI with Uvicorn as the server. The WebSocket works fine when tested through Postman, but disconnects after 60-70 seconds when accessed through web browsers or mobile clients (like Flutter). Below are the details of my setup:
Server Setup:
• Framework: FastAPI
• Web Server: Uvicorn
• Command to Run Uvicorn:
uvicorn.run("main:app", host='0.0.0.0', port=7000, reload=True, workers=4)

• I’m also aware of ping intervals and have tried configuring ws-ping-interval and ws-ping-timeout as shown below:
uvicorn app:app --ws-ping-interval 25 --ws-ping-timeout 60

Issue:
When accessing the WebSocket from a browser or mobile clients (like Flutter), the connection disconnects after around 60-70 seconds, but it works perfectly with Postman.
Logs (Browser Console):


[Error] WebSocket connection to 'wss://dev-api/api/v1/chat/ws?token=...&userId=...' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected
[Info] WebSocket:: – "Connection closed"
[Info] Chat:: – "Error occurred"



What I’ve Tried:

Increased ping intervals and timeouts using --ws-ping-interval 25 --ws-ping-timeout 60 to keep the connection alive longer. This didn’t solve the problem.

Testing WebSocket using Postman: The connection remains stable and does not disconnect when using Postman.

No Nginx or Proxy: I’m not using Nginx or any proxy server, so that’s not a factor here.

SSL/TLS Setup: Currently, I’m not using SSL/TLS for the WebSocket (wss://). Could this be related to the disconnection issue?


Questions:

Why does the WebSocket connection disconnect after 60-70 seconds on browser and mobile clients but works fine in Postman?

Does the absence of SSL/TLS (wss://) cause such WebSocket disconnection issues in web browsers or mobile apps?

What additional configurations should I apply to keep the WebSocket connection alive longer across different clients (especially browsers and mobile apps)?


Any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

wss means that the browser/client expects a TLS encrypted connection. If you're not using TLS, ws would be the correct protocol. Given that the https endpoint on the same host sends other headers than what uvicorn sends by default (and terminates tls), what is the actual structure like? Is there a load balancer (I saw that you said there wasn't a proxy involved, so I'm guessing not).

Where are you running this? On your local machine? Or on some cloud provider?
